# XPath: Retrieve specific parts of a website

Tags: xpath

I have a problem to find the right XPath.

HTML:
`<td class="align-right nowrap"> "49.28" <sup class="negative-value"> "+1.28" </sup> </td>`

My XPath:
`//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[@class='align-right nowrap'][1]`

Result:

> 49.28+1.28

I only want to get the number 49.28. I would be thankful if somebody can help me with this problem.

Comment: SO is an english speaking page. Please translate your question to english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xpath
//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[@class='align-right nowrap'][1]/text()
```